# From vb.NET console application to Windows service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a Console Appplication in Visual Basic, now I want to *translate* it in a Windows service. How can I do that? 
I have choose Project->Properties and then I have selected Windows Service from the drop down menu, but isn't enough, since something is missing (propably an installer?).

What's the complete procedure?

Comment: This is covered well in the MSDN Library, the RTFM pages [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually my question earned more score than your comment.
PS: I know where the doc is, and I already read that. The problem was elsewhere, I resolved it thanks to a person kindly enough to answer a mean question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this page:
[Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Specifically the Section *"Create Installers for your Service:"*

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click Service1.vb or Service1.cs and
   select View Designer.
2. Click the background of the designer to select
   the service itself, instead of any of its contents.
3. With the designer in focus, right-click, and then click Add Installer. By
   default, a component class that contains two installers is added to
   your project. The component is named ProjectInstaller, and the
   installers it contains are the installer for your service and the
   installer for the service's associated process.
4. In Design view for ProjectInstaller, click ServiceInstaller1 for a Visual Basic
   project, or serviceInstaller1 for a Visual C# project.
5. In the Properties window, make sure the ServiceName property is set to
   MyNewService.
6. Set the StartType property to Automatic.
7. In the designer, click ServiceProcessInstaller1 for a Visual Basic project,
   or serviceProcessInstaller1 for a Visual C# project. Set the Account
   property to LocalSystem. This will cause the service to be installed
   and to run on a local service account.